# How to get list id and item id?

Tags: list, javascript, path

I want to share document in page which does not have document library web part (hence I can't get renderCtx).

I need to use this function:

```
DisplaySharingDialog('http://spdev/sites/default','{A967D704-F12E-4A37-A37B-69AF80F64F7E}','27');
```

All what I have is files (list items) url eg. `/sites/default/subsite/Shared Documents/MTT (Training) Application and User Location Diagram.vsdx`

Can I get **list id** and *item id* from document path ?

Starting my jurney with this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://spdev/sites/default/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/default/subsite/Shared Documents/MTT (Training) Application and User Location Diagram.vsdx')",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log('Response',response);
        if (response.d.Exists) {
            var responseIds = response.d.ContentTag.split(',');
            EnsureScriptFunc('sharing.js', 'DisplaySharingDialog', function () {
                ...
            });         
        }
        else {
            alert('Error occured...');
        }
    }
});
```

But this call returns wrong data...

Answer (score 2):

The getfilebyserverrelativeurl endpoint returns an [SP.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246089(v=office.15).aspx) object, so you need to select and expand the "ListItemAllFields" object with your document request to get the list item ([SP.ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245356(v=office.15).aspx)) that corresponds to your document, then you can expand to get the ParentList ([SP.List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245826(v=office.15).aspx)) item for that document

Append this select and expand statement to your list item request:

```
$select=parentList,listItemAllFields/Id,listItemAllFields/ParentList
&$expand=listItemAllFields,listItemAllFields/ParentList
```

Which produces a request URL like this:

```
"http://spdev/sites/default/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/default/subsite/Shared Documents/MTT (Training) Application and User Location Diagram.vsdx')?$select=parentList,listItemAllFields/Id,listItemAllFields/ParentList&$expand=listItemAllFields,listItemAllFields/ParentList"
```

Then you'll have a `ListItemAllFields` Object that includes a `ParentList` Object with your response data.

The id can be found in `data.ListItemAllFields.Id` and the parent list id will be in `data.ListItemAllFields.ParentList.Id`

---

You can use the chrome dev tools to explore the other properties in REST returns like this by performing an ajax request in the console and inspecting the result element, I usually use something like the following (a jquery example)

```
$.getJSON(reqURI, function(data) { window.myJsonData = data });
```

Then I can just bring up the `myJsonData` variable in the window and inspect the object in a fairly user-friendly way.